# I get null pointer exceptions on all my JUnits. in debug - Source not found

Tags: java, junit, nullpointerexception

This JUnit test (and others) always fail because of a NullPointerException. When I debug, it returns an error of "Source not found" at line sq.setPlayers(players); 
Below is a list of the class methods used and their dependencies. I can't imagine any reason why it wouldn't work.

```
public class SingleEliminationTest {

    private Queue queue;
    private Match currentMatch;
    private SingleElimination sq;


    public void setUp() {
        queue = new Queue(4);
        sq = new SingleElimination();
    }

    @Test
    public void setPlayers()
    {
        ArrayList<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();
        players.add("Max Atkins");
        players.add("Hannah Marlow");
        players.add("Liam Ross");
        players.add("Chandlar Bruce");
        sq.setPlayers(players);

        assertEquals("Not enough players", queue.length(), 4);
    }

public class SingleElimination implements IManager
{
    private Queue queue;
    private Match current;

    public SingleElimination()
    {
        queue = new Queue(5);
    }
    /**
     * Set the players or teams to use in the competition
     * @param players the players or teams
     */
    public void setPlayers(ArrayList<String> players)
    {
        for(String player : players)
        {
            queue.enQ(player);
        }
    }

public class Queue 
{
    Object[] queue;
    int head;
    int tail;
    int length;

    public Queue(int startSize)
    {
        queue = new Object[startSize];
        head = tail = length = 0;
    }

    // Adds an Object to the back of the queue. 
     public void enQ(Object o)
     {
         if(length == queue.length)
         {
             //queue = new Object[queue.length * 2];
         }
         queue[tail++] = o;
         length++;
         if(tail == queue.length)
         {
             tail = 0;
         }
     }
```

Comment: all answers were  good, chose the fastest reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to annotate the `setup` method otherwise it won't be run. I'm not very familiar with JUnit but I suspect `@BeforeClass` or `@Before` would do what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `@Before` annotation if you want your setup method to run **before each and every test** (any method annotated with `@Test`), use the `@BeforeClass` annotation if you want your setup method run **once and only once**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate your `setUp` method with `@Before`. It's not being run.